# Mallet and word stems

Tags: text, classification, stemming, mallet

I'm using mallet for a text classification task and it seems to be that mallet is applying some word stemming algorithm on my text. How can I configure mallet to avoid using this feature?

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: This thread may answer your question: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.mallet.devel/822

Comment: You're right Ben, the problem was the accents and apostrophe presents in the corpus that I was using. Thanks a lot :)